# Not able to display photo in html

Tags: php, html

I have a code of HTML where i want to display photo which is uploaded by user.

i tried below mention code. to get it done in html. Please let me know if i have done any mistake in given code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $folder="Images/";
    $tmp_name="";
    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))   
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['photo']) ) {
            $Photo=$_FILES['photo']["name"];
            $tmp_name=$_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"];
            $folder=$folder.$Photo;
            echo $folder;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$folder);
        
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload Photo <input type="file" name="photo">
    <img src=<?php $folder ?> height="200px" width ="200px"> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="  Save  " name="submit_btn" > 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a syntax error in your code I think, instead of the statement `<img src=<?php $folder ?> height="200px" width ="200px">` you should type it like this `<img src="<?php echo $folder; ?>" height="200px" width ="200px">`, So I think that should work as syntax error might be the problem.... Try it!